# Custom Activity Indicator Not Centered

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityindicatorview

I'm using MONActivityIndicator by mownier from github: https://github.com/mownier/MONActivityIndicatorView

This is how I setup the indicator:

```
var activity = MONActivityIndicatorView()

activity.numberOfCircles = 5
activity.radius = 10
activity.internalSpacing = 3
activity.duration = 0.5
activity.delay = 0.3
activity.center = self.view.center

self.view.addSubview(activity)

activity.startAnimating()
```

The problem is that the indicator doesn't show up in the center but at the top-right corner of the view, why is that?

Comment: I have checked the repo now. There is an issue about centering the indicator. You can see it [here](https://github.com/mownier/MONActivityIndicatorView/issues/7). You should add constraints to center the indicator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add constraint into activity view and make it center as done into demo project.

Here is that function in swift:

```
func placeAtTheCenterWithView(view: UIView) {

    self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))

    self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))
}
```

Remove this line from code:

```
activity.center = self.view.center
```

And your final code will be:

```
var activity = MONActivityIndicatorView()

activity.numberOfCircles = 5
activity.radius = 10
activity.internalSpacing = 3
activity.duration = 0.5
activity.delay = 0.3
self.view.addSubview(activity)
self.placeAtTheCenterWithView(activity)  //center it with constraint.
activity.startAnimating()
```

One more way to make it center is do that in main thread this way:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    activity.center = self.view.center
}
```

Comment: Happy to help you..:)